# Summarizing $2^k-k^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Write without summary and calculate.

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (2^k-k^2)$$

This is the part c, got the other 2 quite easily. I wrote down some of the first $n$, $1+0-1+0+7+28+79+...$

Maybe I'm asking more on how to approach this kind of a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just splitting it into two series?

$$\left(\color\red{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}2^k}\right)-\left(\color\green{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k^2}\right)=\color\red{2^{n+1}-2}-\color\green{n(n+1)(2n+1)/6}$$

Comment: The second (green) summation is not on $k$ but on $k^2$ !

Comment: @Zubzub: Oh... Thanks, you're right, I will fix that :)